# Using Geth debug_traceTransaction API

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using debug_traceTransaction API from Geth node. (ropsten testnet)

It works well but sometimes the response gives me

```
{code=-32000, message=transaction c6f08309fa47a817b97a6eae3db04b3818fd7c12296b92098a0fa7c42de4ded4 not found}
```

even the transaction is in the block, but gives me right response when retry the request.

My request is like this.

```
{
    "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
    "id" : 0,
    "method" : "debug_traceTransaction",
    "params" : ["0xc6f08309fa47a817b97a6eae3db04b3818fd7c12296b92098a0fa7c42de4ded4", {"tracer": "callTracer"}]
}
```

Any ideas why it gives not found error..?

Comment: Has the node finished syncing? For some tracing you might need an archive node that stores all intermediate states.

Comment: Yes, the node is synced as full syncmode and archive mode.
I get transactions from the block first then request debug_traceTransaction from that transaction but sometimes it gives not found error.